# ActiveMQ - Consumers not sharing the load 

Tags: c#, activemq-classic

Let's say I have a queue called notifications and I post 1000 messages to that queue.  I also have 20 consumers of that queue.  I'd like each of those consumers to take one message from the queue, process it, then get the next available message.

What is happening now is that a few of the consumers grab a lot of the messages and process them while other consumers do nothing.

Below is a complete test case that demonstrates what I'm seeing.  In reality the consumers are all separate processes on separate machines, but this duplicates the behavior exactly:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Apache.NMS;
using Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ;
using Spring.Messaging.Nms.Core;

namespace QueueTest
{
    class Program
    {
        private static object _syncObj = new object();
        private static int _row;

        static void Main()
        {
            var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
            var template = new NmsTemplate(connectionFactory);

            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            {
                template.ConvertAndSend("notifications", "hello");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Spawn, i);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void Spawn(object o)
        {
            int count = 0;
            int threadId = (int)o;

            var ts = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,5);
            while (true)
            {
                var connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory(
                                "tcp://localhost:61616"
                                + "?nms.PrefetchPolicy.QueuePrefetch=1",
                                String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", 
                Environment.MachineName, 
                threadId, 
                "notifications"));
                using (var conn = connectionFactory.CreateConnection())
                {
                    conn.ClientId = String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}", Environment.MachineName, threadId, "notifications");
                    conn.Start();

                    using (var session = conn.CreateSession())
                    {
                        var queue = session.GetQueue("notifications");
                        using (var consumer = session.CreateConsumer(queue))
                        {
                            IMessage msg = consumer.Receive(ts);
                            while (msg != null)
                            {
                                lock (_syncObj)
                                {
                                    Interlocked.Increment(ref _row);
                                    Console.WriteLine("{0}.  {1} processed {2}", _row, threadId, ++count);
                                    if (_row == 500)
                                    {
                                        Environment.Exit(0);
                                    }
                                }
                                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                                msg = consumer.Receive(ts);
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine("{0} nothing to process", threadId);
                        }
                    }
                    conn.Stop();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get it to spread out the messages to all of the consumers more evenly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after I setup the bounty, I figured out the problem...  :-(

I was using an older version of NMS that didn't support the prefetch policy.

Answer (score 1):

The issue revolves around the prefetch buffer of the consumers.  By default the consumer will prefetch around 1000 messages from the broker.  You need to set the prefetch for the consumers so that they allow the other consumers to get some messages, in your case you might want to set the prefetch to one so that each consumer shares the load evenly.  Take a look at the prefetch policy in the NMS.ActiveMQ API.

you can set the prefetch on the connection URI, it would look something like the following tcp://localhost:61616?nms.PrefetchPolicy.QueuePrefetch=1

Comment: I've tried about a dozen variations of prefetchPolicy=1 including waht you have there and consumer.prefetchPolicy=1 and consumer.prefetchPolicy=0 and jms.prefetchPolicy=1, etc.  They all exhibit the same behavior:  The first XX number of consumers prefetch all the messages.

Comment: Looks like you left out the .QueuePrefetch part, you can't set the entire policy, take a look at the NMSConnectionFactoryTest.cs file in the src/test/csharp folder, it has a test case that sets the prefetch limits.  There is an update that will be in the v1.5.1 release that allows you to set everything in the policy with something like this: nms.PrefetchPolicy.All=1